# display data from database in dialog box

Tags: java, mysql

i am new in using java. Can any one help me in answering this question please ?

Is it possible to display data from database (mysql) in dialog box by using java language?

awaiting your reply and thanx

Comment: Yes, yes it is. (If you were looking for a more elaborate answer, you'll want to write a more elaborate question)

Comment: Yes...why not?...use jdbc for accessing the database and show them in dialog box.

Comment: But please don't mix code that accesses database with one that draws the dialog box! Adopt a layered approach.

Comment: what is your problem , getting data from database or showing it in your dialog box ??

Comment: can you please write the steps that i have to do beacause as i mention shortly i am new in java.. or kindely provide a link that describe the steps.. and thank u very much for ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, such a global answer can only have a global answer:

First [google for JDBC](https://www.google.nl/search?q=jdbc&aq=f&oq=jdbc&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62.1432&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (Java Database Connectivity), and download [MySQL's Connector/J](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/).

After you set up a connection with the above you can query your database for that date. To show it in a dialog box you'll have to format it to a user readable format. Just google for [java convert mysql date](https://www.google.nl/search?q=java+convert+mysql+date&aq=f&oq=java+convert+mysql+date&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j60j62.530&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and you got plenty of examples tutorials and other useful resources.

Comment: i found mysql connector/j and downloaded it, but i haven't found JDBC program, all what i have found about it topics explain what is JDBC, can u help me please and thanx

Comment: That's what I wanted you to find: a page explaining what JDBC is. Did you read this trail: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html?

Comment: Especially the introduction's example code at the top: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html

Comment: thank u very much :), it will read it soon